# How do I make this code more responsive?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a problem with responsiveness. In my example by right side there's 30 px blank place. I don't know how the hell fix it. Does somebody have any idea? http://jsfiddle.net/98p3webw/ details details details details

```
    .imageeee { 

    position:absolute;
    max-width: 100%;


}
.logo{

    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

 .max{
    width: 100%;

    position:relative;

 }
 .background{
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/colorful-triangles-background.jpg");
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
 }


<body>


<div >
    <div class="row">
        <center>
            <img class="logo" src="http://i59.tinypic.com/dcbgiw.png">
        </center>
    </div>

        <div class="background col-md-12">

            <div class="max">


                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                <div class="col-md-8 thumbnail" style="top: 40px;" >
                    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 15 pixel spacing you are seeing are being added by Bootstrap's `row` class.

```
.row {
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
}
```

In Bootstrap, `.row` elements should be wrapped by a `.container` or `container-fluid` element.

### From the [Grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) section of the Boostrap docs:

> Rows must be placed within a `.container` (fixed-width) or `.container-fluid` (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.

So wrapping your `.row` element in a `.container` should solve your immediate problem.

#### [JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/bfknagqm/):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <center>
            <img class="logo" src="http://i59.tinypic.com/dcbgiw.png">
        </center>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Further Reading:

You might want to read over [the Boostrap docs for the grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) so you can make sure you use it correctly in other places. Also, the [`<center>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) tag is deprecated, You should use the CSS [`test-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) property instead.